# activerecord-reputation-system gem prevents from saving a new object

Tags: activerecord

I am following the railscast on adding an Active Record Reputation System. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system)  I have a model Shirt which I'd like users to be able to vote on.  I updated my gemfile with:

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', require: 'reputation_system'
```

I ran a bundle install and restarted the server.  Now when I try to create a new shirt I get a notification that the shirt is missing a name even though I entered it, and I'm unable to create a new shirt.  AS soon as I remove the gem and run bundle install everything goes back to normal and I'm able to create a shirt without a problem.  Any idea what's going on here?

Here are the logs:

```
Started POST "/shirts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500
Processing by ShirtsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eiVOinXgtMUoPGwI5IK3n4GFGWv/0xA8ZdD6b6Pvgko=", "shirt"=>{"name"=>"asfas", "category"=>"Startup", "description"=>"", "url"=>"", "approved"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Submit Changes"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Shirt: name, category, url, approved, description
    app/controllers/shirts_controller.rb:11:in `create'
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered admins/new_shirt.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 318ms (Views: 232.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)


Started GET "/assets/sessions.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/shirts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/custom.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/sessions.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/shirts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/admins.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/admins.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 11:59:18 -0500
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following gem solved this issue.

```
gem 'activerecord-reputation-system', github: 'NARKOZ/activerecord-reputation-system', branch: 'rails4'
```

Comment: It's recommended to use original `activerecord-reputation-system` as it supports Rails 4 now and the bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.0 activerecord-reputation-system supports Rails 4 and that bug was fixed in version 3.0.1